# How to get the AppWidget id that I just clicked?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I need to get the id of the `AppWidget` when I click on it because I need the value to correctly perform certain action have some way to do it in a scalable way? but getting the id of the appwidget that I clicked is already a big help

I use a code to fetch all ids

> But I can not get what I need that's what I clicked on

```
public class AppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static final String MontWidget = "WidgetPreferences";
    private static String ID_CONFIG_WIDGET = "teste_config";

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        RemoteViews views;

        SharedPreferences dados = context.getSharedPreferences(MontWidget, 0);
        Integer posicao = dados.getInt(ID_CONFIG_WIDGET+appWidgetId, 0);

        Log.i("Posicao de selecao", String.valueOf(posicao));

        if (posicao == 0) {

            CharSequence widgetText = Widget_Config.loadTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);

            views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.x1);

            Intent confirmar_acao = new Intent(context, Alert_x1_Activity.class);
            confirmar_acao.putExtra(Alert_x1_Activity.ARG_DIALOG_NUMBER, 1);
            confirmar_acao.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

            PendingIntent confirmar_acao_u = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    0, confirmar_acao, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_X1, confirmar_acao_u);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.txt_x1, confirmar_acao_u);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_x1,widgetText);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }

        if (posicao == 1) {
            CharSequence widgetText = Widget_Config.loadTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);

            views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.x2);

            Intent confirmar_acao = new Intent(context, Alert_x2_Activity.class);
            confirmar_acao.putExtra(Alert_x2_Activity.ARG_DIALOG_NUMBER, 1);
            confirmar_acao.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

            PendingIntent confirmar_acao_u = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                    0, confirmar_acao, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_x2, confirmar_acao_u);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.txt_x2, confirmar_acao_u);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_x2,widgetText);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        System.out.println("onUpdate");
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        RemoteViews views;
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alert_x1_Activity.class);

            intent.putExtra("KEY_ID",appWidgetId);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent, 0);
            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
            // to the button
            views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.x1_widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_x1, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at the example from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AppWidgetProvider):

```
public class ExampleAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExampleActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
            // to the button
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget_provider_layout);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);

            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the for loop, you know the *appWidgetId* for the AppWidget you are currently updating. So you can take this *appWidgetId* and pass it as an `Intent` extra:

```
// ...
// Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExampleActivity.class);
// Put the current appWidgetId as Intent extra:
intent.putExtra("KEY_ID", appWidgetId);
// Use the appWidgetId (or any unique int value) as request code for the PendingIntent. 
// Note: two PendingIntents with the same "content intent" 
// and the same request code *are the same PendingIntent* !
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, intent, 0);
//...
```

In `ExampleActivity`, you get the *appWidgetId* like this:

```
int widgetId = getIntent().getIntExtra("KEY_ID", -1);
```

(Or if you set the launch mode to to "singleTop" or if you used the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag, then the `Intent` with the id will be delivered to `ExampleActivity` in `onNewIntent(Intent)` )

Please note that the appWidgetId's don't start with 0 (I tested with two App Widgets, and they had numbers 5 and 6) But this code snippet is only meant to show you that you can pass information with the `PendingIntent` which will help you to identify your App Widget.(Not only `int` values, please see [Intent.putExtra()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Parcelable)))